# Symbology add field going to all other values

Tags: symbology, arcgis-pro

I am working with a complex symbology in ArcGIS Pro using two fields. The fields are for a cities parcels that have zoning and general plan designations. There are fields that have a null value in them and I have them included in the symbology:

[image]

I want this behavior but what is perplexing is that an attribute field is not showing up in the symbology but is instead going strait to the 'all other values' field.

[image]

There is nothing under the 'select values to add' area.

[image]

The fields in question are both 'text' and have a value (the two fields are shown in yellow highlighter)

[image]

What I would expect is the fields to appear as | Null, A | under the symbology but they just aren't and this has been frustrating me for a good long while.

I have tried to make a new field(s) and copy the values over etc to no effect.

*Edit: Another anomaly is that the 'count' field says that there are zero of the 'all other values' symbology but it accurately recolors what would be the | Null, A | parcels. I've still yet to solve this problem.

[image]